# CSS child element not recognizing parent for proper alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align label text with its corresponding input field using absolute positioning. However, the label is not recognizing my input-div as its parent and seems to be positioning the label text in relation to the outer login-div instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="login-div">
        <form action="" class="form">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <div class="input-div">
                <input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" required>
                <label for="loginName">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div">
                <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" required>
                <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit-btn">
            <a href="#forgot-pw" class="forgot-pw">Forgot your password?</a>
            <p>New member? <a href="#register" class="register">Sign up now!</a></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form .input-div label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[Login and password crammed into corner of form instead of within the input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE4h2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With absolute positioning, you've broken free of the parent box.  Adding `position: relative;` to the `input-div` element, or changing the `label` to `position relative;` may help you position the label in relation to `input-div`.

```css
.form .input-div {
  position: relative;
}

.form .input-div label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;  /* Set width to something appropriate */
  height: 30px;  /* Set this value to something appropriate */
  display: table; /* Optional. May help set an organic line width */
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I did have the input-div position set to relative, but I named it login-div instead. This helped track that down, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the class `.input-div` should be `{ position: relative; }`
otherwise it will be positioned against the closest parent with {position:relative}

it should also have `width` equals to `.form,` equals to `.login-div`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **transform** property

top and left properties rely on the parent's position (relative it, absolute or static). Translations are not affected by that settings. Translation transformations are "identical" to applying top and left when element has position: relative

```
form .input-div label {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(50%, 100%);
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```